# Not able to set value with class declaration

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to set the value. But getting error.
please help me to understand

```
class Y {

    num: number;

    get x() {
        return num;
    }

    set m(i):number {
        this.num = 20;
    }
}
const N = new Y().m(10);
console.log(N.x);
```

Comment: You use `this.num` in your setter, but just `num` in your getter. Also, what do you believe `new Y().m(10)` is? You assign it to `N`, afterall. Also, a setter behaves like a property, and is not callable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `num` is added to the instance of the class. You need to return `this.num` from the getter
- In the setter, you are alwasy setting it to `20`. You need to set it to `i`. This will be value assigned using `=`
- You need to create an instance of `Y` in a separate line.
- You don't call setter like a function. Treat it like a normal property:

```js
class Y {
  num;

  get x() {
    return this.num;
  }

  set m(i) {
    this.num = i;
  }
}

const N = new Y()
N.m = 10;
console.log(N.x);
```

Please go through [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set)

Comment: so, we should not do `N.m(10)` - to set the value? please correct me.

Comment: @3gwebtrain no. Just `N.m = 10`

Answer (score 1):

You called your setter as a function, that never works. Do this instead:

```js
class Y {

    num;

    get x() {
        return this.num;
    }

    set m(i) {
        this.num = i;
    }
}
const N = new Y();

N.m = 23

console.log(N.x); // Prints 23
```

The set syntax binds an object property to a function to be called when there is an attempt to set that property. When you use set, you are not defining a function but rather binding one to the call to set a property. That function gets called when you do something like:

```
myObject.property = some_value
```

The function you bound to the property gets called. You choose what to do within the function which in your case was to set the **num** attribute.
More of it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set)

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `num` using `this.num` keyword and getting with only `num`.

add `this` keyword to `get` method

```
  get x() {
        return this.num;
    }
```